# How to get the name of the user who logged into Tridion CME in GUI Extension

Tags: gui-extensions, user-management

I have a GUI Extension, I want to get the username and description of the user logged in to Tridion and clicked the GUI Extension in Ribbon bar.

Comment: John and Raj already provided answers. For more generic information, see this question on SO and everything related to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171158/how-can-i-retrieve-tcm-uri-of-the-currently-logged-in-user-in-javascript-code

Answer (score 4):

In Anquilla you can use the following as an example:

```
var userSettings = Tridion.UI.UserSettings.getInstance();
alert(userSettings.getUserName());
```

Answer (score 4):

You can user following for get the username & Description

```
var settings = Tridion.UI.UserSettings.getJsonUserSettings(true)
var userName = settings.User.Data.Name;
var description = settings.User.Data.Description
```